# how to add dojox.mvc.Output to dojox.mobile.ListItem programmatically?

Tags: dojo

I want to add a label and value for ListItem programmatically how do i do it? I do not want to use rightText for ListItem.

```
     //   widgetId = "showUrl"
     dojo.empty(widgetId);

     var listItem = registry.byId(widgetId);
     if (listItem != undefined)
          listItem.destroy(true);

     listItem = new ListItem({}, widgetId);

     var labelOutput = dom.byId("urllabel");
     if (labelOutput == undefined) {
         labelOutput = dojo.create("div", {id: "urllabel"}, listItem.srcNodeRef);
     }
     console.log("labelOutput ", labelOutput);
     var output = new mvc.Output({ref: labelItem
                          }).placeAt(labelOutput);
     console.log("output ", output);
     //output.startup();
```

}

I tried the above code and it doesn't show me the label url in ListItem.

Answer (score 1):

Just bumped into this page. In case if using Dojo 1.8 is an option - Dojo 1.8 allows to establish data binding right to dojox/mvc/ListItem's `label` attribute, which is the text in ListItem, with [dojox/mvc/at](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mvc/at.html) API. So you can do something like:

```
var labelItem = new Stateful(); // dojo/Stateful
registry.byId("li").set("label", at(labelItem, "value"));
labelItem.set("value", "The text");
```